Pandas 'Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found'
Here is my data file:

My file is readable and has a list of columns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df.columns)


Why do I get an error when I want to read one column or several?
df2 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['<TICKER>'])



Could you please [edit] your question and replace the images by text versions? This will be more accessible to future readers.

Your CSV is invalid, you have double quotes " wrapping the full lines. Thus they are considered a single field.
You should remove them before trying to read the file as CSV.
Here is an example to pre-process the file to remove the external ":
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

with open('data.csv') as csv:
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('\n'.join(l[:-1].strip('"') for l in csv)),
                     usecols=['<TICKER>'])

Output:
  <TICKER>
0     AFLT
1     AFLT

Another quick-and-dirty approach, assuming you don't have other quoted fields (i.e. only " on the outside of the lines), could be to consider the " as an extra separator:
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',|"', usecols=['<TICKER>'],
                 engine='python', quoting=3)

